# Wordpress custom filter won't work when using REST API

Tags: python, php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-hook

I have a custom filter that moves every file under some criteria to a specific folder. The filter works fine, it could be better but works fine. Every time I upload a CSV file through the WP admin that contains the word couples in it, this file is moved to a specific subfolder.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'move_couple_csv');
function move_couple_csv( $file ) {

    if ((strpos($file['name'], 'couples') !== false) &&  (strpos($file['name'], '.csv') !== false)) {

        $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
        $destinationFilePath = $upload_dir['basedir']."/couples/".$file["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $destinationFilePath);    
        return $file; 
    }

    return $file;
}
```

However, this filter won't work if I use a python client using requests lib and WP REST API. My client is this:

```
#  Upload the CSV file to the WordPress directory

url = 'MYURL/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'
file_directory = "couples_09_09_2021.csv"
file_binary = {'files': open(file_directory,'rb')}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
    'Authorization': 'Basic blahblah',
    'Username': 'username',
    'Password':'password',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + file_directory + ''
}


response = requests.post(url, files=file_binary, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

The upper code will indeed upload the CSV file to the WordPress installation folder, however, the move_couple_csv function under the wp_handle_upload_prefilter hook won't be triggered.

Any ideas?